# Distance between points along line

Tags: qgis-3, point, line, distance

How do I determine the distance between points to the neighbor point that connected via the line(road)?

In QGIS 3.8.3 I have tried `v.distance` and `v.net.distance` but they do not help.

The line(roads) I extract from Quick OSM.

The intersection from Line Intersection features from QGIS

For example, I want the distance between the point
`'718367168'` to `'428716812'`,
`'718367168'` to `'718367169'`,
and so on.

With exception `'718367168'` to `'672464081'` cause not connected via a line(road)

[image]

The layer Nearest and Distance is a fail one

Comment: Main question: are points snap to lines? Do you need a distance to each of the possible clothest points connected via lines? Thus `'718367168'` will have only three neighbours, am I right?

Comment: You could split your lines where your points intersect the roads and simply measure the new road-segments with $length .If you already downloaded osm data, why dont you try out the ors-tool https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ORStools/

Comment: @Taras thank you for edited the question! Yes the points snap to lines because it's intersection between the lines but different layer, and yes '718367168' will have only 3 neighbours. What i want to generate is not only the distance to clothest points, but to all 3 points.

Comment: @DirkB. it will take a lot of time if simple measure the length one by one. how to use ORStools? is it isochrones?

Comment: Yes, you can calculate the length with field calculator once for all at the same time. But you need to split your roads into segements from a to b before.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Shortest Path`:

`Processing toolbox` > `Network Analysis` > `Shortest Path`

There are different options I guess yours is `Point to point`

Comment: I tried that too, the Point option is not the point layer,
and will take a really long time because the total intersection point is 580